# How to match environment-like shell-compatible variable assignment by regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to match something like this.  format is the same with /etc/locale.conf at centos

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

After match, need extract "LANG" and "en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^(\w+)=['"]?(.+?)['"]?$
```

You may want to play with the character(s) of the key/value, depending on your requirements.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/kvrMjR/1)